# How to get localizedstring for CNLabeledValue in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cncontact

In swift 2 I'm using `CNLabeledValue.localizedStringForLabel(phoneNumber.label)` and works fine.

In swift 3 I tried this line `CNLabeledValue.localizedString(forLabel: phoneNumber.label!)` but got `generic parameter 'ValueType' could not be inferred` error

How to get localizedstring for CNLabeledValue in swift3?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Swift 3, `CNLabeledValue` is declared as:

```
public class CNLabeledValue<ValueType : NSCopying, NSSecureCoding> : NSObject, NSCopying, NSSecureCoding {
    //...
}
```

It's a generic type and if you use it in a proper context, you have no need to to cast its `value`. Swift 3 well infers the `ValueType`.

But in your code, Swift has no clue to infer the `ValueType`. It is sort of annoying, because `ValueType` is needless while executing the type method. But the type system of Swift needs it to be specified. If Swift cannot infer the type of the `ValueType`, you can explicitly give it.

Try this:

```
 let localizedLabel = CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: phoneNumber.label!)
```

Comment: Can you provide any additional explanation on why it is necessary to specify `NSString` rather than `String`?

Comment: @MurraySagal, `CNLabeledValue`s generic parameter is declared as `<ValueType : NSCopying, NSSecureCoding>`. So, in this case, you can choose any type which conforms to `NSCopying` and `NSSecureCoding`. `NSString` does and `String` does not.

Comment:   Thank you for figuring this out. Why it's not part of the Swift 3 Converter in XCode escapes me...