# How to declare an empty array of type 'CNLabeledValue' using Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, contacts-framework

The code that used to work in iOS 9 was:

```
var valuesArray : [CNLabeledValue] = []
```

But I can't figure out how to do it in Swift 3.

Comment: `CNLabeledValue` is a generic class in Swift 3, so you can't have something of type `CNLabeledValue` — it has to be `CNLabeledValue<Something>`. Which "Something" it is depends on what you're doing with this array, so there's not much more help we can provide without a bigger picture of how your array is used.

Comment: I'm working with the Contacts Framework, so is an array of CNPhoneNumber.

Comment: 'var valuesArray : [CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>] = []'  solve issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
var phoneNumbers : [CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>] = []
```

As OOPer pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299543/how-to-get-localizedstring-for-cnlabeledvalue-in-swift3):

> `CNLabeledValue`'s generic parameter is declared as `<ValueType : NSCopying, NSSecureCoding>`. So, in this case, you can choose any type which conforms to `NSCopying` and `NSSecureCoding`. `NSString` does and `String` does not.

Comment: The referred sentence may lead some misunderstandings in your case. You may need to choose one appropriate type for `ValueType` -- in your case, it's `CNPhoneNumber`. The part "any type" does not apply to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

something like this (with example to fill out phone number):

```
            let phonesArray : [Phones] = phones!
            var phonesToAdd = [CNLabeledValue]()
            for phone in phonesArray
            {
                if let phoneT = phone.phoneType
                {
                    if phoneT.lowercaseString == "mobile"
                    {
                        let mobilePhone = CNLabeledValue(label: "mobile",value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phone.phone))
                        phonesToAdd.append(mobilePhone)
                    }
                    if phoneT.lowercaseString == "landline"
                    {
                        let landlinePhone = CNLabeledValue(label: "landline",value: CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phone.phone))
                        phonesToAdd.append(landlinePhone)
                    }
                }
            }
            contactData.phoneNumbers = phonesToAdd
```

Comment: The OP designates Swift 3, your code seems to be written in Swift 2.

Comment: Ok, in case of swift 3 make sense to write something like this [CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>]()